how to perform set operations with navigational properties?
I have been trying to create dynamically generated expression trees for filtering models in my database (PSQL, using Npgsql with EF Core). Yet when I try to filter a list of Player models against a list of ids (int ids of Hero model), I get an exception

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'parameter')

I have the following model being mapped:
public class Player : IProfile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public bool? Displayed { get; set; }

    public int? PositionId { get; set; }
    public Position? Position { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Hero> Heroes { get; protected set; } = [];
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; protected set; } = [];
    public ICollection<TeamPlayer> TeamPlayers { get; protected set; } = [];
}

Expression tree is generated and then used in Where in this function depending on filtering parameters provided:
public static IQueryable<Player> FilterWith(this IQueryable<Player> query, PlayerConditions queryConfig)
{
     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Player), "profile");
     Expression expr = Expression.Constant(true);

     if (queryConfig.NameFilter != null)
     {
         var condExpr = GetStringFilteringExpression<Player>(queryConfig.NameFilter, "Name", parameter);

         if (condExpr != null) 
             expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, condExpr);
     }

     // ...
     if (queryConfig.HeroFilter != null)
     {
         var condExpr = GetValueListFilteringOnListExpression<Player, Hero, int>(queryConfig.HeroFilter, "Heroes", "Id", parameter);

         if (condExpr != null) 
             expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, condExpr);
     }

     // ...
     Expression<Func<Player, bool>> finalLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Player, bool>>(expr, parameter);

     return query.Where(finalLambda);
}

The exception occurs when trying to filter the players based on a list of Hero ids passed.
Here's how the HeroFilter expression is created:
public static Expression? GetValueListFilteringOnListExpression<TProfile, TListItem, TListItemProp>(ValueFilter<TListItemProp>? filter, string listPropertyName, string listItemPropertyName, ParameterExpression parameter) where TProfile : class, IProfile
{
    var listType = typeof(ICollection<TListItem>);
    var property = typeof(TProfile).GetProperty(listPropertyName);
    var listItemProperty = typeof(TListItem).GetProperty(listItemPropertyName);

    if (filter == null || property == null || property.PropertyType != listType || listItemProperty == null || listItemProperty.PropertyType != typeof(TListItemProp)) 
        return null;

    var listItemType = typeof(TListItem);
    var valueList = Expression.Constant(filter.ValueList, typeof(ICollection<TListItemProp>));
    var memberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);

    var intersectByMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "IntersectBy")
        .Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 3)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TListItem), typeof(TListItemProp));

    var countMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
       .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
       .First(m => m.Name == "Count" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
       .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TListItem));

    var listItemParameter = Expression.Parameter(listItemType, "li");
    var listItemPropertyEx = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(listItemParameter, listItemProperty);
    var listItemPropertyLambda = Expression.Lambda(listItemPropertyEx, listItemParameter);

    //var countProperty = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TListItemProp)).GetProperty("Count");
    var intersectByExpression = Expression.Call(intersectByMethodInfo, memberAccess, valueList, listItemPropertyLambda);
    //var intersectedCount = Expression.Property(intersectByExpression, countProperty);
    var intersectedCount = Expression.Call(countMethod, intersectByExpression);

    Expression? finalExpression = null;

    switch (filter.FilterType)
    {
        case ValueListFilterType.Exact:
            {
                var valueCount = Expression.Constant(filter.ValueList.Count);
                finalExpression = Expression.Equal(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                break;
            }

        case ValueListFilterType.Including:
            {
                var valueCount = Expression.Constant(filter.ValueList.Count);
                finalExpression = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                break;
            }

        case ValueListFilterType.Excluding:
            {
                var valueCount = Expression.Constant(0);
                finalExpression = Expression.Equal(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                break;
            }

        case ValueListFilterType.Any:
            {
                var valueCount = Expression.Constant(0);
                finalExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                break;
            }

        default:
            break;
    }

    return finalExpression;
}

I am still figuring out how to debug LINQ, but I've tested my filtering function against a List of Players in memory directly and it works! It filters correctly. So, after looking around a little more I've discovered that not all C# Collection functions have translations to SQL syntax in Npgsql (seemingly it's only Collections.Contains). Is that my problem here? If so, what's the best way to perform set operations with navigational properties?

So you want to build p => p.Heroes.Any(h => h.something == "")? (aka Expression.Any(p.Heroes, ...)) You should be able to reuse most of your dynamic expression tree construction for the inner lambda.

Not quite, I need to compare a list in the model against a list of ids. I've made simple value comparisons with expression trees, sure, but set operations elude me. I want to execute them on the DB, not in memory.

I did it. I was using IEnumerable methods, when LINQ to SQL needs IQueryable, a cast to IQueryable with AsQueryable was all that was needed (and methods being from Queryable):
 public static Expression? GetValueListFilteringOnListExpression<TProfile, TListItem, TListItemProp>(ValueFilter<TListItemProp>? filter, string listPropertyName, string listItemPropertyName, ParameterExpression parameter) where TProfile : class, IProfile
 {
     var listType = typeof(ICollection<TListItem>);
     var property = typeof(TProfile).GetProperty(listPropertyName);
     var listItemProperty = typeof(TListItem).GetProperty(listItemPropertyName);
     if (filter == null || property == null || property.PropertyType != listType || listItemProperty == null || listItemProperty.PropertyType != typeof(TListItemProp)) return null;
     var valueList = Expression.Constant(filter.ValueList, typeof(ICollection<TListItemProp>));
     var memberAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, listPropertyName);
     var asQueryable = typeof(Queryable)
         .GetMethods()
         .First(m => m.Name == "AsQueryable" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition);
     var asQueryableListItemProp = asQueryable.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TListItemProp));
     var asQueryableListItem = asQueryable.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TListItem));
     var select = typeof(Queryable)
         .GetMethods()
         .Where(m => m.Name == "Select" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
         .Single(m =>
         {
             var parameters = m.GetParameters();
             if (parameters.Length != 2)
                 return false;

             var delegateType = parameters[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
             return delegateType.IsGenericType && delegateType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>);
         }).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TListItem), typeof(TListItemProp));
     var intersect = typeof(Queryable)
         .GetMethods()
         .Where(x => x.Name == "Intersect")
         .Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TListItemProp));
     var count = typeof(Queryable)
         .GetMethods()
         .First(m => m.Name == "Count" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TListItemProp));
     var listItemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TListItem), "li");
     var listItemPropertyEx = Expression.Property(listItemParameter, listItemPropertyName);
     var listItemPropertyLambda = Expression.Lambda(listItemPropertyEx, listItemParameter);
     var asQueryableExpression = Expression.Call(asQueryableListItem, memberAccess);
     var valueListAsQueryable = Expression.Call(asQueryableListItemProp, valueList);
     var selectExpression = Expression.Call(select, asQueryableExpression, listItemPropertyLambda);
     var intersectExpression = Expression.Call(intersect, selectExpression, valueListAsQueryable);
     var intersectedCount = Expression.Call(count, intersectExpression);
     Expression? finalExpression = null;
     switch (filter.FilterType)
     {
         case ValueListFilterType.Including:
             {
                 var valueCount = Expression.Constant(filter.ValueList.Count);
                 finalExpression = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                 break;
             }
         case ValueListFilterType.Exact:
             {
                 var valueCount = Expression.Constant(filter.ValueList.Count);
                 finalExpression = Expression.Equal(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                 break;
             }
         case ValueListFilterType.Excluding:
             {
                 var valueCount = Expression.Constant(0);
                 finalExpression = Expression.Equal(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                 break;
             }
         case ValueListFilterType.Any:
             {
                 var valueCount = Expression.Constant(0);
                 finalExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(intersectedCount, valueCount);
                 break;
             }
         default:
             break;
     }
     return finalExpression;
 }


If you're going to write your FilterWith method so explicitly, you might as well skip the dynamic linq expression trees and call .Where() repeatedly, which will behave as if each filter is && together;
public static IQueryable<Player> FilterWith(this IQueryable<Player> query, PlayerConditions queryConfig)
{
    if (queryConfig.NameFilter != null)
        query = query.Where(p => p.Name == queryConfig.NameFilter);
    if (queryConfig.HeroFilter != null)
        query = query.Where(p => p.Heroes.Any(h => h.Id == queryConfig.HeroFilter));
    // etc
    return query;
}

I would only build an expression tree dynamically if none of your code knows which properties to filter.
Even if you want to || terms together, it is much simpler to modify two expression trees than to build everything from scratch.

I was going to reuse the expressions for some other models and simply decided to get some expression tree practice. I know that LINQ combines Where calls.
I guess it wasn't written as clearly, but HeroFilter has a property ValueList which, well, a list of ids. So I need to compare the related Heroes in each Player (Heroes is a nav property to a MTM relationship) to a list of ids based on filtering behaviour (if Player.Heroes includes all the ids in the list, has any of the ids in the list, has exactly the same ids as the list, etc).
Problem is making an expression that executes on DB.
